# How to prioritize future features (enterprise web development)

Tags: project-management, enterprise

Suppose you're the product manager for an internal enterprise web application that has 2000 users and 7 developers. You have a list of 350 future features, each ranging from 5 to 150 developer days of work.

How do you choose what features to work on, and how do you run the release process?

Here's what I'm thinking: (skip if boring)

- **Release Process.** Work on several features at once, release each individually when it's ready. The other option (what we've been doing up to this point) is to pick out a certain set of features, designate them as "a release", and release them all at once (announcing via mass email).

  The advantage of a shorter release process is that we can release features as soon as we finish development. The advantage of a bigger process is that it's easier to organize.
- **Feature Prioritization.** Put all the future features in a spreadsheet with columns for feature, description, comments, estimate, benefit, (your) estimate, (your) benefit. Give copies to 2 senior engineers, the other senior project manager and yourself.

  The engineers estimate all the features (how precisely? consulting each other?). To determine benefit, everyone allocates points (total = 10 * [number of future features]) among the future features (without consulting each other?), compare scores and average (?).

  Another potential strategy here is to just rank each feature on an absolute (say) 1-100 scale. Having an absolute ranking is nice because it makes prioritizing as our feature list changes easier (we don't want to have to redistribute points every time someone proposes a new feature).

What's your strategy? Do any books / websites attack the problem at this level of detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great book that helps cover this topic called *Agile Estimating and Planning* by Mike Cohn. It has some great ways to estimate and plan releases. Including a planning game called planning poker where the engineering team gets together with cards to estaimate user stories. Each engineer plays a card 1,2,3,5,8,13 face down. The high and low card explains and you do it again. After 1 or 2 repeats there is generally convergence on the same estimate.

There's also *Beyond Software Architecture: Creating and Sustaining Winning Solutions* by Luke Hohmann which might help with some of the product management related pieces and the reasoning to use to prioritization. I have not yet read the book but I went to a talk by Luke Hohmann where he covered the subjects of his book and I can't wait to read it.

Also I would recommend reading books on various Agile Development processes such as Scrum, Crystal Clear, and XP. There's *Agile Project Management with Scrum* by Ken Schwaber and *Crystal Clear: A Human-Powered Methodology for Small Teams* by Alistair Cockburn. Also *Extreme Programming Explained: Embrace Change (2nd Edition)* by Kent Beck and Cynthia Andres.

As for feature prioritization, that is generally done by the stakeholders. You need to work on the features that address the needs of your stakeholders, which, as Luke Hohmann points out, includes the system architecture.

However, one of the most important things is to make sure that you have agreement on the software development process from the team. If you force a process and the team doesn't believe in, then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't have 350 *independent* features, some must depend on others.
Put them all into some task management software which allows you to define which tasks depend on which other ones, and you might soon find that you've got a much easier decision process...

Answer (score 0):

As for the release process, you could introduce the features when they are ready and inform the users via a company blog that is updated whenever a new feature is done. Such a blog entry should then give a short overview about the feature, where to find it, how to use it, etc.
Not only does this keep your users curious and coming back, it also offers a great way of potential customers to check out the progress of your offering.

As for prioritizing future implementation: how about involving the customers there as well? Look at uservoice (it is used to track requests/bugs for this site). It offers a nice way of letting the users vote on most desired things as well as showing what is being worked on and what is planned.

Answer (score 0):

"rank each feature on an absolute (say) 1-100 scale"

Build them in order.

Release them when you've got (a) significant value or (b) critical mass of small things.

Always work in priority order.  Build the most important stuff first.  Deliver as much value as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

a few people here have already said it - involve the end users in the decision process of what goes in and what waits. after all, its not about whats useful to you, but whats useful to your end user.

that said, i wouldnt leave it open to 'all users to decide'; there should be a representative from the user group who you work with (i.e. senior user role).

even then, you arent saying "what features do you want?" to the user, you ask them what functionality they would like to see arrive next. the reason why you put it to them that way rather then letting them pick off a massive spreadsheet of individual features is two-fold: 1) they dont know about dependancies, 2) you want to gather together a pack of features for a logical release.

so the user representative may say "we need to have the photo gallery working next". they might not be aware that the  photo galery is practically the same as the file upload module (it just accepts different file types).

so, in the next release version, you pack together the photo gallery and the file upload - why wouldnt you, considering that the file upload is like 75% done because of the work that went into the photo gallery module?

i dont believe you necessarily have to work on the hardest features first, its what the users need sooner + what other features you gather together to make a 'logical pack'.

to a certain extent, you want to clear the feature log too. so for example, you could have the following features and estimaed times:

1. Registration Form - 3 hrs
2. Photo Gallery - 8 hrs (<- client has said they want this next)
3. File Upload - 2 hrs
4. Voting/Poll module - 7 hrs
5. Stock Ticker - 5 hrs

out of these contrived features, i would take no. 2 (because the client is asking for it), then i would take no. 1 and 3. no. 3 because its practically done when the gallery code has been done, and no. 1 purely because its the smallest estimate out of the remaining features. nothing will give you or your coding crew the feeling of progress on your project like seriously beating down the feature list (it will probably refill though).

as far as letting people know about a new release and whats in it, i would do it via email (rather then by blog or within the program itself). and i would make it as brief as possible, bullet points, something like this:

===

Version 1.1 of *Blue Widgets* has just been launched and is available for your use now.

The following has been added:

- Photo Gallery
- File Upload
- Registration Form

The user manual within the system contains more information on how these features work.

===

bang - done, make it as easy for people as possible.

- LM